# React + Redux Updated State Not Getting Re-Rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying out React + Redux and I came upon the problem of the most people. React is not updating (re-rendering).

I have read other posts regarding the same issue but I am still unable to solve my problem.I was able to update the state but I am unable to update the props for the component.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

ActionCreator -

[image]

Reducer -

[image]

[image]

Store -

[image]

App -

[image]

React -

[image]

Developer Tools -

[image]

Comment: could you provide full gist

Comment: Try to print in console `state` variable in `mapStateToProps` function. What value is displaying, after you dispatched actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd try to do its changing passing props from:

```
 ErrorMessage: state.ErrorMessage
```

to particular props, in your case isVisible

```
 isVisible: state.ErrorMessage.isVisible
```

And of course after that update the line with visibility to:

```
visibility {this.props.isVisible}
```

Its because you're passing whole object and changing only props inside of it. My guess is that React doesnt detect changes like this. Let me know if it helps!

EDIT:
I googled this issue and I found that, may be useful for you:
http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-not-rerendering

Regards, 
  Mariusz

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it is working fine now. I will be trying this out again with objects. Thanks!